# Running a Powershell script from R using system2() rather than system()

Tags: r, powershell

I have a PowerShell script (say at C:\directoryName\coolScript.ps1). If I want to invoke this from R, I can run

```
system('powershell -file "C:\\directoryName\\coolScript.ps1"')
```

If I try to do the same with `system2()`, it returns no error, but the script is not executed. Since the documentation for the `system()` command says that `system2()` "is recommended for new code", I would like to use `system2()`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unlike with `system()`, the `command` argument to `system2()` is always quoted by [shQuote](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/shQuote.html), so it must be a single command without arguments, while arguments are passed to `command` with the `args` argument.

Both of them works :

```
system("sed -i 's/oldword\\s/oldword/g' d:/junk/x/test.tex")
system2("sed", args=c("-i", "s/oldword\\s/newword/g", "d:/junk/x/test.tex"))
```

I would try :

```
system2("powershell", args=c("-file", "C:\\directoryName\\coolScript.ps1"))
```

---

**Another thing you should be aware of** is that there are two versions of the R executable in R-3.2.1\bin\i386 (32-bit) and R-3.2.1\bin\x64 (64-bit).  By default only the first is installed on 32-bit versions of Windows, but both on 64-bit OSes. The 32 bits version of R will invoke the 32 bits version of PowerShell and the same for the 64 bits version so be careful to use `Set-ExecutionPolicy` for the right one.

Comment: Presumably if someone is getting a `system('powershell ...')` call to work, then they have already set the relevant execution policy, but that point is essential to getting `system2()` to have the desired effect for people who come here without a working `system()` call.